# Desktop App w/ Database - How to handle data retrieval?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, desktop-application

Imagine to have a **Desktop application** - could be best described as record keeping where the user inserts/views the records - that relies on a DB back-end which will contain **large** objects' hierarchies and properties. How should data retrieval be handled?

Should all the data be *loaded* at start-up and stored in corresponding Classes/Structures for later manipulation or should the data be retrieved only at need, stored in *mock-up* Classes/Structures and then reused later instead of being asked to the DB again?

As far as I can see the former approach would require a bigger memory portion used and possible waiting time at start-up (not so bad if a splash screen is displayed), while the latter could possibly subject the user to delays during processing due to data retrieval and would require to perform some expensive queries on the database, whose results and/or supporting data structures will most probably serve no purpose once used*.

Something tells me that the solution lies on an in-depth analysis which will lead to a mixture of the two approaches listed above based on data most frequently used, but I am very interested in reading your thoughts, tips and real life experiences on the topic.

For discussion's sake, I'm thinking about C++ and SQLite.

Thanks!

**assuming that you can perform on Classes/Objects faster operations rather than have to perform complicated queries on the DB.*

**EDIT**

Some additional details:

- No concurrent access to the data, meaning only 1 user works on the data which is stored locally.
- Data is sent back depending on changes made *humanly* - i.e. with low frequency. This is not necessarily true for reading data from the DB, where I can expect to have few peaks of lots of reads which I'd like to be fast.
- What I am most afraid of is the user getting the feeling of slowness when displaying a complex record (because this has to be read in from the DB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Lazy Load](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html) and [Data Mapper](http://books.google.com/books?id=FyWZt5DdvFkC&printsec=frontcover&hl=ru#v=onepage&q&f=false) (pg.165) patterns.

Comment: There are more than 500 pages in the book.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question depends on too many variables to be able to give a concrete answer.  What you should consider first is how much data you need to read from the database in to your application.  Further, how often are you sending that data back to the database and requesting new data?  Also, will users be working on the data concurrently?  If so, loading the data initially is probably not a good idea.

After your edits I would say it's probably better to leave the data at the database.  If you are going to be accessing it with relatively low frequency there is no reason to load up or otherwise try to cache it in your application at launch.  Of course, only you know your application best and should decide what bits may be loaded up front to increase performance.

Comment: Added some further details above.

Comment: Thanks Pete for your input. It is true I will send data back with low frequency but not necessarily I will read it with low frequency too (meaning for instance - tree like operations, needing to fetch lots of nodes with their properties, etc). What I am most afraid of is the user getting the feeling of slowness when displaying a complex record (because this has to be read in from the db).

Comment: Can you do some kind of "prefetch"?  A lot of times it's possible to tell what the user will need "next" in a record keeping application.  For example, if your user is editing a a certain item and is at a screen where they need to enter information before moving on to another screen.  You know that this user will most likely move to that next screen so fetch the necessary data in the background while they are putting information in on the first screen.  There's lots of ways to make the data transfer process fairly transparent for the end user.

Comment: Maybe I don't have the correct prospective on this but in the scenario of the user specifically navigating a complex and large tree how can I guess what to prefetch ensuring that what the fetcher will choose, will be that one node he'll be visualizing? I'm leaning more and more towards multithreading loading of all the data after an initial fetching of "must-know" data. Which still leaves a large memory footprint but which I guess I can live with.

Comment: I cant account for every scenario in your app, all I can do is provide generalizations.  With the information you provided it's hard to say anything for certain.  For example, you said "large" objects with large being in bold but what is large?  How much space in memory does your "large" object take up?  Have you done any testing to see what kind of loads your app will be putting on the database and on the client?

Comment: As I am still in the design phase, I don't have analysis on the loads. However, I would like to design keeping in mind scenarios when 10,000+ records will be available in a tree-like hierarchy - thus my doubts on how/when to fetch data. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider to user intermediate server (WCF) that will contain cached data from the database in memory, this way users don't have to go every time to the database.  Also since it is only one access point to for all users if somebody changes/added record you can update cache as well.  Static data can be reloaded every x hours (for example every hour). It still might not the best option, since data needs to be marshaled from Server to the Client, but you can use netTcp binding if you can, which is fast and small.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. Unfortunately, I feel this goes however well beyond the Desktop Application scenario (i.e. no network) and that even if I do implement such an intermediate layer which fetches from memory, I'd simply shift the "loading" problem to another place/moment.